# How can I generate scaffolding as code in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, scaffolding

I have a cakephp app with some controllers using scaffolding for the logic and views... How can I make cake actually generate those as files and functions in my project that I can then modify and take ownership of...

It's nice to have this stuff as a starting point, but it can't be true that I need to start basically from scratch if I want to change the model properties that are exposed on the scaffold generated list page.